# Youtube-dl autonumber 03d start number

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I'm downloading a playlist with youtube-dl . I'm using this command line :

```
youtube-dl -i -f best -a playlist.txt -o "[VID]%(autonumber) 03d %(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

The first video always got the number 1 , example : [VID] 01 Video Title .

What flag do I need to add if I want to start from for example 500 .

I've tried `-segment_start_number 500` and  `--playlist-start 500` , not working for .

Thank you for help .

Comment: How is this related to programming and Python?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm newbie , can you tell me in witch forum this question would be appropriate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , I've found my own answer

```
youtube-dl -i -f best -a playlist.txt --autonumber-start 500 -o "[VID]%(autonumber) 03d %(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

So the `--autonumber-start 500` it's the answer .